# Is it best practice to use pd.to_datetime on columns of dtype timestamp?

Tags: pandas, group-by, python-datetime

I am using pandas on a dataframe with the following dtypes.

```
order_id:   int64  
order_date: datetime64[ns]  
promo_code: bool  
order_fare: float64

df = pd.DataFrame(data=
                  {"order_id":{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3,"3":4,"4":5,"5":6,"14":15,"15":16,"16":17},
                   "order_date":{"0":"2021-09-25 00:00:00","1":"2021-09-14 00:00:00","2":"2021-08-31 00:00:00",
                                 "3":"2021-08-30 00:00:00","4":"2021-08-25 00:00:00","5":"2021-08-16 00:00:00",
                                 "14":"2021-08-31 00:00:00","15":"2021-08-24 00:00:00","16":"2021-08-14 00:00:00"},
                   "promo_code":{"0":False,"1":False,"2":False,"3":False,"4":False,"5":False,"14":True,"15":True,"16":True},
                   "order_fare":{"0":12.47,"1":7.89,"2":12.38,"3":1.69,"4":11.27,"5":18.16,"14":16.13,"15":14.89,"16":19.72}})
```

I want to groupby the month.

I used:
`df = df.groupby(df.order_date.dt.month)`

I got errant results because the groupby statement
df.order_date.dt.month
produced blank/null(?) results for two entries (order_id: 15 and 16).

Discovering this, when I ran:
`df['order_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['order_date'])`
before the groupby statement, everything worked as expected.

Can someone explain why this happened
and
is it best practice to always run to_datetime on cols already marked as datetime?

Thanks all!

Comment: Can you provide the rows that yielded null months in a reproducible format? Running again `to_datetime` shouldn't change the data. Do you have NaTs?

Comment: Hi Cruton! Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you run df.to_dict() and add the results to your question?

Comment: @mozway I was perhaps imprecise in my language. I should have said I got a blank result for order_ids 15 and 16. I am not positive a blank result is the same thing as null/NaT.

Comment: Hi! nothing special when reproducing your experiment, with rows 15, 16 or any other.
Requesting df = df.groupby.... is little weird because you overwrite your initial data with a particular processing of it. Better use another variable name. Makes me wonder if your report doesn't come from messing with your initial df?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how what you report could be possible. A non-object dtype indicates that the underlying data is stored in an homogeneous format (usually a number) and indicates how to interpret the data. For instance, `datetime64[ns]` is an integer that represents the number of nanoseconds since 1970-01-01.

Thus, if you already have a `datetime64[ns]` dtype, the Series necessarily only contains numerical values (or NaN), nothing else is possible. The only way to have something other than a number in the 1-12 range running `df['order_date'].dt.month` would be to have a NaN/NaT.

Using your example, all value correctly produce a month:

```
df['order_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['order_date'])
df.order_date.dt.month

0     9
1     9
2     8
3     8
4     8
5     8
14    8
15    8
16    8
Name: order_date, dtype: int32
```

If we change one of the date_order values to an empty string before conversion to datetime64 (for instance the last value), you effectively get a NaN because the date is a NaT:

```
df.loc['16', 'order_date'] = ''
df['order_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['order_date'])
df.order_date.dt.month

0     9.0
1     9.0
2     8.0
3     8.0
4     8.0
5     8.0
14    8.0
15    8.0
16    NaN
Name: order_date, dtype: float64


df['order_date']

0    2021-09-25
1    2021-09-14
2    2021-08-31
3    2021-08-30
4    2021-08-25
5    2021-08-16
14   2021-08-31
15   2021-08-24
16          NaT
Name: order_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```